# Error Occurring sorting Time data

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

This is a small piece of a data analysis program I developed to read many rows and decide upon structures.  One part of the macro relies on the time signatures of each row of data.  I wrote this code to sort the time so that it runs from earliest to latest since the default is latest to earliest (top to bottom).  It has been working fine until some data had time signatures mixed around a little bit (i.e. 19:01:16,19:00:00, 18:52:07.......18:48:05)  It sorted approximately 3 quarters of the data correctly and then it randomly restarts again (meaning the earliest data is towards the end ascending again.  Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
'Formats Time data to avoid consolidated trade structures
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Range("b3:b" & lastRow).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:Q278")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]h:mm:ss AM/PM;@"
```

Comment: The time strings you show `2PM`, `202PM` will not be interpreted as times by Excel, so they will be sorted as strings.  If you want information to be properly sorted, you must first make the data consistent.

Comment: Maybe your data is a mixture of date time serial numbers formatted as time and text that only _looks_ like time

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I should have been more specific I was typing quick.  they're displayed initially in this format: 19:01:16 etc.  I will edit post.

Comment: @chrisneilsen it appears to be time.  When the raw data is imported it is listed as 19:07:16 and then if I look at the formula bar it shows 7:01:16 PM

Answer (score 0):

Issue was very stupid unfortunately.  The data had grown to a point outside my expected size and so the sort range was not capturing the last few rows unfortunately.   Apologies for a silly question.

```
'Formats Time data to avoid consolidated trade structures
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Range("b3:b" & lastRow).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:Q5000")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]h:mm:ss AM/PM;@"
```

Comment: Always be dynamic when defining areas in Excel - especially if you are already coding in VBA.